# JPA Function Dependency of a table

Tags: java, jpa

In my 'Country' table column 'countryName' is referenced by 'City' and 'State' table and now i need to check my database tables referenced column via JPA for the Given countryName. Is is possible without use of NativeQuery. I tried it via NativeQuery but I need either NamedQuery or Query.

Comment: can you post your native query

Comment: select * from information_schema.key_column_usage where table_schema = 'test', this is the query i have used at MySQL

Comment: Post your JPA entities and your current JPQL/Criteria query.